# How to Remember Game State by Saving data as an Array in NsUserDefaults

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2

I've build a simple App called Mad Lib. In here you enter 11 times a word into a textfield. The words get Appended to a list called wordStack. You click the button OK and prepare for segway takes the user to a second screen. In here the 11 words are filled as strings into a text.

Example for txt on second page: "Tarzan is also called (wordStack[1])"

So, as I'm reading it seems that when accessing property's in user defaults the content is immutable and also it's for simple data like a single string or maybe an integer. I'm having a reaaaalllyy hard time getting this to work with this array.

So it's kinda working except for the fact that

```
var wordStack: [String] = []
```

Resets workstack every time.

Anyone helping me out and doing some explaining of what would be a good solution is an absolute hero! Thanks!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let s = userDefault.valueForKey("wordstack"){
        var wordStack: [String] = []
        for i in s as! NSArray {
            print(i)
            wordStack.append(String(i))
            print(wordStack)
        }
    }

    print(wordStack)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  @IBOutlet weak var guess: UILabel!

  @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

  // Save game state.
  var userDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

  // Saves the user's input.
  var wordStack: [String] = []

  func test() {
    let userInput = textField.text
    textField.text = nil
    if wordStack.count < 10 {
        wordStack.append(userInput!)
        guess.text = "\(11-wordStack.count) guesses left!"
        userDefault.setValue(wordStack, forKey: "wordstack")
    } else {
        wordStack.append(userInput!)
    }
  }

  // When pressed enter in the textfield append the input to workstack and refresh textfield for new input.
  @IBAction func enterTextField(sender: AnyObject) {
    test()
  }

  @IBAction func buttonClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    if wordStack.count <= 10 {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Wacht", message: "Je bent nog niet klaar. \(wordStack.count)/11 woorden ingevuld.",preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alertController,animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let secondViewController: ViewController2 = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2
    if wordStack.count > 10 {
    secondViewController.outputMessage = "One of the most silly characters is named Tarzan of the bees. Tarzan is raised by an/a \(wordStack[0]) and lives in the \(wordStack[1]) in the heart of the darkest \(wordStack[2]). He spent most of his time eating \(wordStack[3]) and swinging from tree to \(wordStack[4]). Whenever he gets angry he beats on his chest and says \(wordStack[5])! This is his way cry. Tarzan always dresses in smelly \(wordStack[6]) shorts made of the skin of an/a \(wordStack[7]) and his best friend is an/a \(wordStack[8]) Chimpanzee called Cheetah. He is supposed to be able to speak to elephants and \(wordStack[9]). In the movies, Tarzan plays \(wordStack[10])"

    // reset guesses
    //var count: Int = 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly. You didn't reach to store and retrieve you array within NSUserDefaults ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you declare a local variable `wordStack` which is not identical to the instance property with the same name.

Variables declared with `var` are always mutable even when reading values from user defaults.

Easy solution is to remove the `var` keyword before `wordStack` in `viewDidLoad()`

**Better solution:**

Register the key / value pair in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` of `AppDelegate` with

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let defaultValues = ["wordstack" : [String]()]
defaults.registerDefaults(defaultValues)
```

Then just replace

```
if let s = userDefault.valueForKey("wordstack"){
    var wordStack: [String] = []
    for i in s as! NSArray {
        print(i)
        wordStack.append(String(i))
        print(wordStack)
    }
}
```

with

```
wordStack = userDefault.objectForKey("wordstack")
```

As there is a default value of an empty array `wordStack` can never be `nil` and is type safe.

Note: use always `objectForKey` rather than `valueForKey` unless you really need the KVC method.